# Undefined In Initial Function Which Is Calling a Recursive Function

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, recursive-datastructures

I am wondering if there is anyway for me to correct my code so that I can return the object I need to my original calling function.

onAccountSelected calls my recursive function. Is there any way here for me to get my final match inside of my initial calling function - onAccountSelected - by returning that final match from my recursive function?

I have tried this:

```
private findMatch(accountNodeName, currentNode) {
    if (currentNode.children) {
        for (var i = 0; i < currentNode.children.length; i++) {
            var current = currentNode.children[i];
            if (accountNodeName === current.name) {
                return current;
            }

            // return won't work here because I'm returning even if a match isn't found
            return this.findMatch(accountNodeName, current);                

             // this gives me undefined a bunch and then the actual answer once a match is found
            this.currentTreeNode = this.findMatch(accountNodeName, current);
            // console.log(this.currentTreeNode);
        }
    }
}

private onAccountSelected(account) {
  if (account.nodes) {
        this.currentTreeNode = this.findMatch(account.nodes.name, this.gridTreeNodes.BssNode);
        //getting undefined here, would like the matching node to come here
        console.log(this.currentTreeNode); //getting undefined here
    } 
}
```

Comment: Return something that lets you decide whether to break and `return` or continue searching? You'll need to use an `if` statement.

Comment: I am using an if statement to see if the two names equal, if they do I'm returning the current node. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: I'm talking about the "*return won't work here*" comment. Do the `return` conditionally.

Comment: doesn't work, same result

Comment: How did you change it?

Comment: I made it work by just passing the match onto the next function that needed it and breaking rather then trying to "return current" inside the if statement in my loop. I don't believe returning the recusive part of the function will ever come back to the initial function call in my bottom function.